# Necessity of Silverlight App Signing

Tags: silverlight

Hi all at stackoverflow,

Is it really necessary to get my Silverlight app signed before I get it hosted on to the web? Can I do it without it, bearing in mind that I'm not a major company or business but I have written and designed the app for a small company?

Kind regards

Will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a few Silverlight apps running on the web and have never dealt with signing. I can't say for certain that it won't be a problem under some circumstances, but in general signing isn't required.